# In Reactjs, how to trigger and respond to a user defined event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know you can do the following in render to handle click event, but how to respond to a user defined event, such as "newUserAdded".

```
<button onClick={this.handleAddNew}> Add Friend </button>
```

Here is what I mean by example:

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var myEvent = new Event('newUserAdded');
ele.addEventListener('newUserAdded', function () {alert('newUserAdded triggered')});
ele.dispatchEvent(myEvent);

// then you get an alert message
// how to do this in reactJS?
```

I am thinking of the following way to send message among React components:

```
var User = React.class({

   ...
   emitNewUserEvent: function (e) {
      // trigger the new user added message
      // how? 
   },
   ...
});

Var DropDownSelection = React.class({

   // in this component, I'd like to respond to 'NewUserAddedEvent' to add 
   // the newly added user to drop down list
   // how? 

});
```

Please advise! Thanks!

Comment: Who wil trigger it?

I think react with Flux are build to avoid such things, when events come from different places, not related to element. 

And if it is view that draw button, why you need events, just call function.

Comment: you can just `alert` inside your `handleAddNew` new functions, as this functions deals with adding new users. so it gets called every time you add a new user

Comment: to Antom M.: user will trigger the event in the callback func after new user is successfully added. I am not familiar with Flux, but it is a good idea to learn it now.

Comment: To knowbody: If that way, it will defeat the purpose of the event-message pattern, which is to promote the decoupling among components.